# Javascript: My .textContent works, but not my innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, nextsibling

I have a strange problem. In general, when I set a variable as `textContent`, it shows it, but it doesn't when I set it as `innerHTML`

More precisely

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Dynamic Menu</title>
</head>
<body id="top">
    <h1>The Extremadura Region of Western Spain</h1>
    <h2 >Geography Of The Region</h2>
    <p>The autonomous community of Extremadura is in western Spain alongside the Portuguese border.
    It borders the Spanish regions of Castilla y Leon, Castilla La Mancha and Andalucía as well as Portugal (to the West). 
    Covering over 40,000 square kilometers it has two provinces: Cáceres in the North and Badajoz in the South.</p>

    <h2>Where To Stay</h2>
    <p>There is a wide range of accommodation throughout Extremadura including small inns and guest houses ('Hostals') or 
    think about renting a 'casa rural' (country house) if you are travelling in a group.</p>

    <h2>Climate</h2>
    <p>Generally Mediterranean, except for the north, where it is continental. Generally known for its extremes,
    including very hot and dry summers with frequent droughts, and its long and mild winters.</p>

    <h2>What To See</h2>
    <p>Extremadura hosts major events all year round including theater, music, cinema, literature and folklore. 
    Spectacular venues include castles, medieval town squares and historic centers.
    There are special summer theater festivals in the Mérida, Cáceres, Alcántara and Alburquerque.</p>

    <h2>Gastronomy</h2>
    <p>The quality of Extremaduran food arises from the fine quality of the local ingredients. 
    In addition to free-range lamb and beef, fabulous cheeses, red and white wines, olive oil, honey and paprika,
    Extremadura is particularly renowned for Iberian ham. The 'pata negra' (blackfoot) pigs are fed on acorns in the
    cork-oak forests, the key to producing the world's best ham and cured sausages.</p>

    <script src="lunch.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the script

```
function lop(){

var hs = document.getElementsByTagName('h2');
for(var g = 0; g<hs.length; g++){
    hs[g].setAttribute('id', g);
}
var budy = document.getElementById('top');   //Gets the body id
var nnn = document.createElement('nav');   //Creats a nav event
var uuu = "<ul >  \
                <li id='one'> <a href='#0'>Geography Of The Region </a> </li>  \
                <li id='two'> <a href='#1'>Where To Stay </a> </li>  \
                <li id='tre'> <a href='#2'>Climate </a> </li>   \
                <li id='for'> <a href='#3'>What To See</a> </li>  \
                <li id='fiv'> <a href='#4'>Gastronomy</a> </li>";
// li: 55-60 make the HTML              
nnn.innerHTML = uuu;     //Sets the HTML to the nav
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0]; // Get the specific element
budy.insertBefore(nnn, h);  // inserts the element nav and the whole html before h

var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var hih = '<a href="#top"> AAAAA </a>';
for(var g = 0; g<ps.length; g++){
    ps[g].nextSibling.innerText = hih;
}

}

lop();  //cals the function so it executes
```

So basicly in this exercise i have to create an `ul` within the script and without modyfing the HTML.

I successed in creating an `ul`. Then I have to creat a link that brings me to the top of the page. Which is this part here:

```
var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var hih = '<a href="#top"> AAAAA </a>';
for(var g = 0; g<ps.length; g++){
    ps[g].nextSibling.innerText = hih;
}
```

Here I try to creat a link that bring me back to the top. Im using the advantage that chrome has blank space betwwen sibling to creat that link in there.

The problem is that it doesn't show. When I go to my debugger, I have no errors, but nothings shows. If change `ps[g].nextSibling.innerText = hih;`  for `.textContent` it shows the whole think.

I know the difference between `.innerHTML` and `.textContent` (or I think), so why doesn't it show my link and can I make it show ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand you use `nextSibling`. If you want to use `innerHTML`, you can use bellow script

```
ps[g].innerHTML = ps[g].innerHTML + hih;
```

You can read about `nextSibling` in https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nextsibling.asp

Comment: I'm actually trying to add a link in the nextSibling, because I know that in chrome the sibling between the tags are blank

Comment: Because nextSibling of p tag is not a HTML tag, so you can't use innerText or innerHTML. You can others property same textContent as data, nodeValue, It will show same result

Answer (score 0):

Ok so a friend of mine changed my procedure and here what he did:

```
var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var hih = '<br /><br /><a href="#top"> To the top </a> ';

for(var g = 0; g<ps.length; g++) {
    ps[g].innerHTML += hih;
}
```

In other words, what I learned from this 3h of js, is that you can't change a blank child's HTML, but only his text.

Comment: my answer is same as your answer. I don't understand that

Comment: I realized that after, I just didn't understand when you explained. I'm sorry.